# Number of connections exceeding instance count * maxpool

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

We host a website on Microsoft Azure and we have Traffic Manager distributing traffic on two AppServices each with 15 instances and a maxpool size of 80 in the connection strings.

We also use P11 database which has a max connection count of 2400

From our understanding, the maximum possible connections would be:

> Instance count * maxpool
>   30 * 80 = 2400

But we get errors regarding exceeding the maximum allowed number and to our surprise, running a query on the database to show us active connections yields 2600.

We don't have any webjobs running.

Can someone please explain what is happening?

Comment: very stupid question but, are your sure you're closing SqlConnection in your code?

Comment: can you paste exact error message and also can you share the query you used to get results.can you also run this query  `select session_id,count(*) as cnt from sys.dm_os_tasks group by session_id` and share the result

Answer (score 2):

Using the following query you can identity which program name have the most sessions, which login name creates the most sessions, which host creates the most sessions.

```
SELECT
    c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.encrypt_option,
    c.auth_scheme, s.host_name, s.program_name,
    s.client_interface_name, s.login_name, s.nt_domain,
    s.nt_user_name, s.original_login_name, c.connect_time,
    s.login_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id
```

The following statement shows you the maximum number of connections for the current tier.

```
SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS AS 'Max Connections';
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo